# How to create a table on top of this data?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hql

The data looks like the below

```
name:Jack Reacher||Age:30||Place:Ohio||ID:43730||inorg:abcd office||file:qwertyu/werty/ghj/dfhj.jpg
name:Jack Reacher||Age:30||Place:Ohio||ID:43730||inorg:abcd office||file:qwertyu/werty/ghj/dfhj.jpg
name:Jack Reacher||Age:30||Place:Ohio||ID:43730||inorg:abcd office||file:qwertyu/werty/ghj/dfhj.jpg
```

On top of this data I've created a table to map according to data But, the data is constant until there is new line key starting with like the below

New line:

```
name:Jack Reacher||Age:30||Place:Ohio||ID:43730||inorg:abcd office||file:qwertyu/werty/ghj/dfhj.jpg
SIA:uewi||Age:30||Place:Ohio||Qtype:Jame/tyler/on.txt/||ID:43730||inorg:abcd office||file:qwertyu/werty/ghj/dfhj.jpg
name:Jack Reacher||Age:30||Place:Ohio||ID:43730||inorg:abcd office||file:qwertyu/werty/ghj/dfhj.jpg
name:Jack Reacher||Age:30||Place:Ohio||ID:43730||inorg:abcd office||file:qwertyu/werty/ghj/dfhj.jpg
SIA:uewi||Age:30||Place:Ohio||Qtype:Jame/tyler/on.txt/||ID:43730||inorg:abcd office||file:qwertyu/werty/ghj/dfhj.jpg
name:Jack Reacher||Age:30||Place:Ohio||ID:43730||inorg:abcd office||file:qwertyu/werty/ghj/dfhj.jpg
```

How to create table and schema for this? I've tried map string through table but it didn't worked out.

Can you tell me which delimiter to use to create a table and get the key values for the data.

I've tried

```
Create table dataset (
    name string,
    SIA string,
    Age string,
    Place string,
    Qtype string,
    ID string,
    inorg string,
    file string
) ROW SEPERATED BY '||' stored as textfile;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write custom FORMAT SERDE as the format you specified does not fall in any of below category.

```
Avro (Hive 0.9.1 and later)
ORC (Hive 0.11 and later)
RegEx
Thrift
Parquet (Hive 0.13 and later)
CSV (Hive 0.14 and later)
JsonSerDe (Hive 0.12 and later in hcatalog-core)
```

Either you need to modify data file and repalce  || with , and make it json and then use **JsonSerDe**

or try [RegEx](http://hadooptutorial.info/processing-logs-in-hive/)

Comment: Hey I've aslo tried Create external table( name map <string,string>  delimiter String, SIA map <String,string> Delimiter string,

Comment: What ever you use external table or table we required SERDE  as your data is not in any of standard format ..

Comment: Isn't there any possible solution then?

Comment: Do you mean for regex the value won't be consistent right? Can you specify any example?